# How do I customize the IIS 404 page for an Azure Function Proxy?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have the following proxy configured to essentially catch all requests and redirect them to my backend:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "Proxy1": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/{*url}"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://mybackend.com/{url}",
            "debug": false
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine in displaying my custom 404 page that is configured on mybackend.com if the {url} path does not exist.

For example: `https://proxy1.com/bad-path` will show `https://mybackend.com/bad-path` using my backend 404 page as expected.

However, I have found an edge case (maybe this is a bug?) which allows a path to not properly redirect. If you add `%20` to the end of the path, it breaks the proxy path detection, and instead shows the IIS 404 page from the proxy itself. For example:

`https://proxy1.com/bad-path%20`

results in:

[image]

This has caused an issue during a server audit we recently had performed. We cannot show raw IIS error pages like this.

How can I either 1) Fix this proxy issue so that adding `%20` to the end of a path still proxies to my backend where I show my custom 404, or 2) Customize this raw IIS error page so that it is not the standard IIS page shown in the screenshot above?